# Recursive conditional cumulative products

Tags: r, purrr

My data is a series of two rates, i.e. percentage changes.  I want to calculate the cumulative product of each, but reset that cumulative product to 1 every time the product for rate A is <= the product for rate B.

I'm currently using a for loop, which works fine.  I'd love a solution using `purrr`, but the `accumulate` function is limited to at most 3 arguments for the accumulating function, and I need 4.

Appreciate any suggestions, MRE is below.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(20191008)

#create our data
df <- tibble(time = 1:100,
             #A and B represent two rates, i.e. percentage change
             A = runif(100) + 0.5,
             B = runif(100) + 0.5,
             #initialize the value of the cumulative products as 1
             CumeProdA = 1,
             CumeProdB = 1)


#Current solution uses a loop, but it's slow with large data
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
  #If the cumulative product of A <= that of B, then reset it to 1.
  #Otherwise, continue accumulating
  df$CumeProdA[i] <- ifelse(df$CumeProdA[i - 1] * df$A[i] <= df$CumeProdB[i - 1] * df$B[i],
                            1,
                            df$CumeProdA[i - 1] * df$A[i])

  #Ditto with B
  df$CumeProdB[i] <- ifelse(df$CumeProdA[i - 1] * df$A[i] <= df$CumeProdB[i - 1] * df$B[i],
                            1,
                            df$CumeProdB[i - 1] * df$B[i])
}



#I've done similar recursive calculations using purrr::accumulate,
#but it has a limit to how many arguments you can use in a function
df %>% 
  mutate(Example = accumulate(A, ~ ifelse(.x * .y < 1, 1, .x * .y)))


#The ultimate goal is to find the greatest difference in the cumulative products.
#If there's a shortcut to get to here, I'll take it!
df %>% 
  summarise(min(CumeProdB - CumeProdA))
```

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorizeed

Comment: @akrun thanks for your response, do you mind expanding a little?  How would you leverage the fact that `ifelse` is vectorized to address the recursive nature of this calculation?

Comment: Sorry, at first I was thinking not in terms of recursive.  Anyway, if you are passing one row at a time `if/else` is enough

Comment: You can use `accumulate2` with `CumeProdB`

Comment: Are you sure about your example data? It seems to me that CumeProdA and CumeProdB should be initialized to first values of A and B rather than 1. That way, for the calculation of CumeProdA[2], the product A[1]*A[2] would be evaluated, rather than 1*A[2].